# Intellij incorrectly highlighting error in bean definition with spring

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

[image: incorrectly highlishted error]

[image: correct app context]

`Could not autowire bean should be off type ..NamedPArameterJDBCTemplate`

Which is wrong on two counts ... ?

Comment: Has it got anything to do with the space in your xml file at the beginning of the class attribute? Or possibly worth a try; ensuring you have the Spring facet configured...

Comment: @Ed. O M G Y E S. thats a bit lame, shouldn't the error appear in applciation context. Remove the space and everythign works. Thanks muchly.

Comment: Haha! Well good news, but agreed, bit lame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a space at the beginning of your class attribute value in your XML file.